# Floating fibres in Bochet mead

Tags: mead, contamination, troubleshooting

I made a Bochet style mead (burnt honey mead) and it's spent about a week bubbling away,  but there's some strange fibrous floaties that I've never seen before,  circulating around the must.

They even seem to form little dunes,  up to a few centimetres deep on the bottom of the 5 litre demi.

Is this anything to worry about? My previous meads never had this,  but this is my first Bochet.

[image: a little hard to photograph, note the dunes at the bottom]

1.8kg honey,  caramelised 
~20 sultanas
Mangrove Jack M05 yeast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks normal**

Some yeast will flocculate into snowflake clumps or even strands.

Jack M05 is rated as a high flocculation yeast.

Comment: I guess it's just the sheer amount of it... in comparison, the mead next to it  (and another previously) has about 6mm of silty trub at the bottom, same yeast, same honey.

Comment: Bochet may be what's different. hydroxymethyl furfuraldehyde (HMF) is created when honey is heated, even small amounts is toxic to bees. I've not seen any research to support, but it's possible that is stressed the yeast changing its life cycle and traits.

Comment: Ahh interesting, that could be it then... neither of the others were heated much past 60c.

Comment: Can confirm. My bochet looked like this too. I just assumed it was either yeast clumping in a weird way or burnt proteins from the honey itself.